# QGIS Desktop 3.10.9 with GRASS 7.8.3 doesn't work in Windows 10

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I just installed QGIS LTR (qgis-ltr-full) from OSGeo4W in Windows 10 (version 2004), but when running QGIS with GRASS I get the following error:

[image]

```
qgis-ltr-bin-g7.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point
?glyphCache@QFontEngine@@QEBAPEAVQFontEngineGlyphCache@@PEBXW4GlyphFormat@1@AEBVQTransform@@@Z
could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\OSGEO\apps\qtS\bin\Qt5OpenGL.dll.
```

And after "Aceptar":

[image]

```
Error loading QGIS

Oops, looks like an error loading QGIS
Details:
Could not load qgis_app.dll
Windows Error: No seencontró el proceso especificado.
Help:
Check C:\OSGEO\bin\qgis-ltr-bin-g7.env for correct environment paths
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Delete the next path of the qgis-ltr-bin-g7.env file: "C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin".

Answer (score 2):

Update the qgis-ltr-grass-plugin7 package to the latest version 3.10.10-3.

See https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/641#comment:15 and https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/0f2b53c9494f4f3d98f46bf8af079071d68a4281

EDIT: it seems qgis-ltr-grass-plugin7 3.10.10-3 doesn't yet fix the issue. A new patch https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/04fbe177b9412de6fc01ef337540a7885656677e was merged and will be hopefully fix the issue in the next QGIS version.